# Rails - Variable inside the find()

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a system where a user inputs a symptom and gets a list of illnesses that match that symptom.

For this, I have `symptoms` and `illnesses` tables with `has_many through` relationship through a secondary table.

To find all illnesses that have a symptom with the id of 42, for example, I'm using `Symptom.find(42).illnesses`.

However, I want this id to be supplied by the user, instead of the static number it is now, but I can't find a way to do so.

Comment: You might be looking for a Rails tutorial that covers stuff like this, in particular http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-articles (except you've got Symptoms instead of Articles)

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps. I do have index and show actions but index seems to receive the id from the url which I assume is very counterproductive when I want to find a list using a user-supplied id and, eventually, more than one id

Comment: counterproductive how so?

Comment: Because, I assume, through that method the system will be limited to one symptom when I want the user to be able to input several

Comment: it sounds like you're expecting users to input multiple symptom IDs by number. I don't think this is going to happen.

Comment: Not by number, but through a dropdown that shows the name of each symptom. I have done similar before (to associate symptoms to illnesses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a controller to show symptoms and illnesses associated with these symptoms.

```
class SymptomsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @symptom = Symptom.find(params[:id])
    @illnesses = @symptom.illnesses
  end
end
```

In your routes add `resources :symptoms, only: [:show]` if you are creating a show method only so you can access a certain symptom via `/symptoms/42` for example. List the illnesses in the view afterwards.

Comment: That is closer to what I need, but wouldn't it limit it to just the one symptom? I was thinking of having it only show the illnesses that match 1~N symptoms informed by the user.

Comment: Then you can use a query like `Illness.joins(:symptoms).where('symptoms.id IN (?)', [42,43,44])` where the array `[42,43,44]` is an input parameter from the user.